# How to use Django FilterSet with MultiSelectField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a `FilterSet` using `django_filters` so users can filter through other user's profiles using filters such as `city`, `age` and `gender`.

Those 3 fields in the FilterSet work fine, however I also want to filter by `interest` which is a `MultiSelectField` based on `INTEREST_CHOICES`.

A user should be able to check multiple interests and filter based on those, in addition to the 3 fields listed above.

I have been unable to get this to work.

I managed to display an interest filter field however when a user selects one of the 4 interests from the dropdown box, the page does not return any matches, even if one of those interests is matched.

I suspect it is because users select more than one interest, thus the interests are saved in a list and not individually, therefore the `FilterSet` can't find the standalone interest.

If someone could look over my code and point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    INTEREST_CHOICES = (
                ('FITNESS', 'Fitness'),
                ('CHURCH', 'Church'),
                ('VEGANISM', 'Veganism'),
                ('MOVIES', 'Movies'),
    )

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
            ('X', 'Neither')
    )

    user            = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interests       = MultiSelectField(choices = INTEREST_CHOICES)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age             = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    gender          = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Profile

class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = {
            'city': ['iexact'],
            'interests': ['exact'],
            'age': ['iexact'],
            'gender': ['exact'],
        }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_filter(request):
    f = ProfileFilter(request.GET, queryset=Profile.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'profile/profile_filter.html', {'filter': f})
```

urls.py

```
path('filter', user_views.profile_filter, name='profile_filter'),
```

profile_filter.html

```
<h1>Filter people.</h1>
      <form method="GET">
          {{ filter.form|crispy }}
          <button type="submit" class="small">Search.</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to filter by exact match, rather you want to filter by checking if the filter param is contained in the interests list. So you should change your filter like this:

```
class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = {
            'city': ['iexact'],
            'interests': ['icontains'],
            'age': ['iexact'],
            'gender': ['exact'],
        }
```

**EDIT**: To allow filtering by multiple interests.

Here you have to write a custom method to parse the interests and convert them to arrays before filtering. They will usually come as a string with comma separated values.

Add the method to the filter class as follows:

```
class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    interests = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='interests', method='filter_interests')
    city = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='city', lookup_expr='iexact')
    age = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='age', lookup_expr='iexact')
    gender = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='gender', lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['age', 'city', 'gender', 'interests']

    def filter_interests(self, queryset, name, interests):
        return queryset.filter(interests__contains=interests.split(','))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to filter with multiple interests though? For example, if I type in `vegan` right now, it returns profiles with `veganism`. However if I type in `vegan fitness` it returns none even though there are profiles matching those 2 interests. What would you suggest to make this more efficient? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the help. I get the error `filter_interests() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` when I type in any interest or multiple interests. I added `self` to the arguments which gets rid of the error but then doesn't return any results?

Comment: @Trillz I forgot to add the `self` argument. Edited

Comment: I added that earlier but it doesn't return anything now when an interest is typed in?

Comment: @Trillz the issue was probably because `interests` wasn't in the Meta fields. I have edited the answer to accommodate that. Looks like the extending the Meta and defining the fields inline won't work together

Comment: Still doesn't return anything unfortunately, although I really appreciate your help. The only method that filtered by interest successfully was the `icontains` solution.

Comment: That's weird. I use a similar setup in my project and it works. Of course you can change the `contains` to `icontains` for case insensitive filtering.